# How to use PnP module with DXA 1.4 java with SDL web 8

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.4, personalization, profiling

I want to try PnP module using Target Group with DXA 1.4 Java. I think Context expression module is introduced in DXA 1.5 which we cannot upgrade at this point of time.

Can you guide me how I can implement the same functionality with DXA 1.4?

Any pointer is a great help.

Comment: Why is an upgrade considered so problematic that you consider investing in back-porting DXA 1.5 functionality to DXA 1.4?

Comment: We  already have stable version of Java DXA 1.4 and we make it Live, So at this point of time we cannot upgrade DXA version. We just want to implement some personalization use case using PnP funcationlity, We are exploringfor some way through which we can achieve basic personalization capability, may be using target group author can add conditions to component presentation and in DXA code we filter required component presentation and  discard other CP. If you can guide where we should write such code in JAVA DXA 1.4, then it will be a great help.

Comment: You can't upgrade, but you can make (potentially high impact) changes to the Web App and TBBs?

Comment: @RickPannekoek , I know Up-gradation is better options, but we have done some customization  on the existing JAVA DXA 1.4, and I didn't find any document where it is clearly mentioned that what changes we need to do in CMS and CDA to upgrade DXA version from 1.4 to 1.6/7.  I checked online document of DXA 1.6 at URL:http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6
But I didn't find clear up-gradation steps. If you can guide me where should I look for this then it will be a great help.

Comment: I have added another blog for PnP implementation with full issue details at URL: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16466/sdl-web-8-with-java-dxa-1-4-pnp-conditions-are-not-getting. So may be we can close this